# Ionide's codelens in F# doesn't show (vscode)

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

After reinstalling my Mac, codeLens doesn't work all of a sudden.

I'm using vscode for mac with the ionide-fsharp extension installed. Usually it was enough to have CodeLens active, where I'd see the signatures above my code.

[image][image: ][1]]

The "int" above "let a = 5" is what I was used to be using, and it was such a pleasant feature.

Comment: Do you have dotnet installed as well?

Comment: Doh! I thought I installed it, but after (perhaps) reinstalling dotnet framework and sdk it worked :) Thanks!